# Navbar position over image

Tags: html, css

I'm making a gaming site and I'm having some troubles with text positions. What im trying to achieve is having my navbar text ontop of a custom navbar backgroud

[how it looks now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g4qmW.jpg)
[navbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h54t6.png)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
   <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">


  <style>
  body  {
     background-color: black;
     height: 100%;
     margin:0;
     padding:0;
   }    

 .topnav{
     position:absolute;
     text-align: center;
     margin:auto;
     width: 50%;    
  }

 .topnav a {
     line-height: 200px;
     padding: 50px;
     display: ;
     color: #f2f2f2;
     text-align: center;
     text-decoration: none;
     font-size: 17px;
  }

  .navbackground {
     position:absolute;
     top: -50px;
     left:0;
     right:0;
     bottom: 700px;
     margin:auto;
     width: 50%;    
  }

  .banner {
     position:relivent;
     top: 10px;
     left:0;
     right:0;
     bottom:0;
     margin:auto;
     width: 100%;
    }
 </style>
 </head>

 <body>


 <div class="topnav">
   <a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>
   <a href="#news">News</a>
   <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
   <a href="#about">About</a> 
 </div>

  <img src="nav.png" class="navbackground ">
  <img src="wallpaper.JPE" class="banner" >


  </body>
  </html>
```

I was considering adding the nav.png as a background image in the topnav class but i couldn't seem to get it to scale if you no how to scale it correctly or have any suggestions please let me know!

ps.. I'm new to CSS, HTML please cut me some slack :)

Comment: Is the problem that the texts are not over the image (by means of one layer on top of the image)? Or also that the texts are not in position?

Comment: Also, you have some errors on your CSS: `position:relivent`, `display: ;`, etc

Answer (score 2):

Even tough `z-index` property works (it controls how do elements stack on each other), since you have stated you are new to HTML, you should understand that probably the best way to achieve what you need is to correctly order your elements.

You now have:

```
topnav
  link1
  link2
  link3
topnav background
webpage background
```

The elements are rendered on the way you write them. So, for example, to get the background to be rendered **first**, you have to write it first.

```
webpage background -- this will be rendered first
topnav
  link1
  link2
  link3
topnav background
```

Also, for the topnav background, you need to place it before the topnav. But if also what you want is for the topnav to be relative to the background, you also will need to nest them:

```
webpage background
topnav background -- background is the parent of topnav
  topnav
    link1
    link2
    link3
```

That way, the order of rendering is:

- Draw webpage background
- Draw topnav background
- Draw topnav (nothing here, just a placeholder)
- Draw links

As you can see, your topnav in this case is kind of useless. You can just apply a background to the topnav and discard the `topnav background` element:

```
webpage background
topnav -- here we apply the background using background CSS property
  link1
  link2
  link3
```

I hope that made it clear. You can achieve the same results without changing your HTML using `z-index`, but I recommend first to have a clear HTML and semantic.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set `z-index` (higher one for nav)
More on [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp).

Comment: what do you mean by z-index? where do i add/set this

Comment: There is a link with more information. Add `z-index` for example `z-index:999;` in CSS for `topnav` and `z-index:1;` for banner.

Comment: The problem is when i set my Navbarbackground to z-index: -1 then it gets covered by my header background if that makes sense?

Comment: I don't know how do you mean it, can you provide some fiddle example? Btw if you would like to make background, use CSS  `background-image` instead of  `img` element.

Comment: ** I'm having some troubles with text positions ** This just makes the text in the foreground but doesn't change the position of it.

Answer (score 0):

```
topnav{
   z-index: 1000;
}
```

> You need to add z-index to the parent of Nav.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this? ;)

Basicly in your code, give your `.topnav{ ... }` a position of `relative` + give it the background image as I did in this fiddle. Then make a new html div with a `class="nav"` and add the css `.topnav .nav{ position: absolute; left: 10%; width: 80%; }` and give the `.topnav a` a style of `line-height: 60px; width: 24%; display: inline-block;`

I think that were like almost all changed I made.

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.topnav {
  display: block;
  margin: 20px auto;
  width: 80%;
  height: 60px;
  background-image:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/h54t6.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size:100%;
  position: relative;
}

.topnav .nav {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10%;
  width: 80%;
}

.topnav .nav a {
  line-height: 60px;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  width: 24%;
}

.navbackground {
  position: absolute;
  top: -50px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 700px;
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
}

.banner {
  position: fixed;
  top: 20px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <body>
  <img src="https://cdna.artstation.com/p/assets/images/images/005/718/562/large/josh-bruce-headerfinal.jpg?1493246411" class="banner">
    <div class="topnav">
      <div class="nav">
        <a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>
        <a href="#news">News</a>
        <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
        <a href="#about">About</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting it as a background image would be the better option, in my opinion. 
You can scale the background image using the background-size CSS property which you set to either contain or cover (Depending on how you want it to behave if the aspect ratios of div and png don't match, see https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp). 
Rather than scaling the background I'd suggest either scaling the image in an image editor to match the size of your navigation-div or setting the dimensions of the div to match your png.
Same for the background image. You could make it the background-image of the body or a surrounding div.

Here's an example: https://jsfiddle.net/hg5jxn3s/7/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style>
  body  {
     background-color: black;
     height: 100%;
     margin:0;
     padding:0;
     background: url(wallpaper.JPE) no-repeat top left;
     background-size: cover;
   }    

 .topnav{
   background:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/h54t6.png) no-repeat top left;
   background-size: contain;
     position:relative;
     text-align: center;
     margin:0px auto;
     width: 900px;    
     height: 150px;
     padding:70px 0px;
  }

 .topnav a {
     line-height: 1em;
     padding: 0px 50px;
     color: #f2f2f2;
     text-align: center;
     text-decoration: none;
     font-size: 17px;
  }
 </style>
 </head>

 <body>


 <div class="topnav">
   <a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>
   <a href="#news">News</a>
   <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
   <a href="#about">About</a> 
 </div>


  </body>
  </html>
```

You'll notice that I've changed the width from flexible (50%) to a fixed width. I've done this because the navigation items themselves don't scale in your setup, so at a certain size they'd break into a second row which doesn't work with that background-image that well.

You can see what it would look like if you change the above CSS for topnav to:

```
.topnav{
    background:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/h54t6.png) no-repeat top left;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    position:relative;
    text-align: center;
    margin:0px auto;
    width: 50%;    
    height: auto;
    padding:70px 0px;
}
```

see https://jsfiddle.net/hg5jxn3s/10/